# Java: Inherit and Be a Singleton

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

To begin with, I am **NOT** trying to create a subclass of a singleton class. (At least I'm sure I'm not trying to).

I have a class `ClassA` that is abstract.

I have two classes, `ClassA1` and `ClassA2` that extend `ClassA`.

I want `ClassA1` and `ClassA2` to be singleton classes. I could just write the code in each one to do so but I would prefer to write the code once in `ClassA` and reuse it in all of it's sub-classes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Given that it takes about three lines of extra code to make a class into a singleton, I am not sure that whatever potential saving you're hoping to make is really worth the extra complexity...

Comment: What code are you using to guarantee the classes will be valid singletons?

Comment: aix, you're right. It isn't worth the extra complexity. The goal is form the super class in a way so that each subclass wouldn't have to rewrite any functionality and all of the core functions will be done by the super, unfortunately the concept of a singleton class makes this a little difficult.

Colin D, i'm using a standard pattern, I just wanted to see if I could make it generic in some way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not - the singleton pattern requires static methods/fields, which would be shared by `ClassA` and all its subclasses if defined in one place.

Comment: Also, if you're going to make singletons, try looking at [this pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) for a thread-safe singleton, assuming that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest private constructors for `ClassA1` and A2 and having static methods for object creation. This way you have complete control over object creation. 
The book EffectiveJava details out the adavatages of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The only place this is done is in the enum classes which extend Enum. It uses a language twist, and something like `class ClassA<T extends ClassA>`. Either you do:

```
public class ClassA {

    private static final Map<Class<? extends ClassA>, ClassA> singletons = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T extends ClassA> T get(Class<T> klazz) {
        T singleton = klazz.cast(singletons.get(klazz));
        if (singleton == null) {
            try {
                singleton = klazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                    | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
            singletons.put(klazz, singleton);
        }
        return singleton;
    }
    protected ClassA() { }
}
```

Or you rethink your desire of plural singletons, and either do a general container lookup, (maybe with declarative XML or annotations) or a bean container. EJB 3.1 is very nice and simple.

Comment: This is similar to what I have now actually, I was curious to see if I could do this with out any parameters in the `get` method.

Comment: Unfortunately because of type erasure not; you need the class to instantiate the singleton.